# Unable to get Facebook user age_range

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a portal which has the following functionality to comment on FaceBook posts:
1. When a user chooses to a comment on a post, FB credentials of that specific user are requested.
2. When that user signs in with FB credentials my FB app asks for public profile permission.
3.When I use the access token of the same app in the graph explorer it does not return me the age_range of the users (irrespective of whether they are logged in or logged out of FB) who have approved/not approved my app.
4. I have checked for the public_profile permission even on the access token as well, using the debug feature in graph explorer but still I'm not getting the age_range.
Can anyone tell me step by step procedure to get the age_range of a user?

Comment: The users need to have "installed" your app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#optimizing

Comment: @Tobi What exactly do you mean by 'installed'? Kindly explain.
<br> By 'installed' do you mean that age_range will only be rendered for FB canvas apps?

Comment: This means a user went through the OAuth process successfully IMHO

Comment: @Tobi can u plz elaborate further...this is really imp for me!

Comment: same problem with me, I am developing an iOS app which requires Facebook login, but unable to get the "age_range" using the Graph API. @Tobi, if you can elaborate a bit further would be helpful, because what facebook documentation is saying is not happening. Thanks.

Comment: @AmitShil What do you need the `age_range` for? Do you request it via the `/me?fields=id,age_range` call?

Comment: I am working in an app where I am using personalisation using persons age,gender etc.....so I need at least "age_range" if user logs in to the app using facebook.  I am using facebook graph API for iOS...                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                     //here I get the all the public information of the user in "result" object but age_range is missing
                 }];